# Create and send file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I may create file and send it to server in internet explorer 8 ?

Now I am doing it for ie9(and above) so:

```
var blob = new Blob([data], {//data is long xml-string
    type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8;"
});
var file = new FormData();
file.append('xml_file', blob, 'file.xml');
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: file,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: 'text',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        console.log(xhr);
    }
});
```

Comment: If it's just a long XML string, why would you need a blob to send it to the server, just send the string

Comment: Note that `Blob()` is only suported on IE10+, IE9 doesn't support it. http://caniuse.com/#feat=blobbuilder

Comment: Should MIME type of `Blob` be `"application/xml"` or `"text/xml"` ?  What is purpose of third parameter passed to `FormData` ? Does `js` at Question not return expected results ?

Comment: @adeneo i must send file with expansion .xml to server

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, since you're using jQuery. It's very simple to use and works well with many features.

https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html